# Use of @ in Python

Tags: python

I was seeing the methods and docs of the built in `super()` method of python using the `help()` function in the IDLE .
I came across this piece of code

`This works for class methods too: |  class C(B): |      @classmethod |      def cmeth(cls, arg): |          super().cmeth(arg)`

In the second line , you can see the `@` sign before `classmethod` .

What does the `@` symbol does in python and what are its uses ?

Comment: Please **always** use the generic [python] tag for all python-related questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@` character denotes a decorator. Decorators are functions that can modify or extend behavior of another function temporarily by wrapping around them.

Decorators wrap around a function by receiving them as a parameter. The `@` syntax (also known as "pie" syntax) applies the `classmethod` decorator to `cmeth` after it is defined in your snippet.

You can read more about the specific decorator from your example (`classmethod`) [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod).

Comment: The decorator syntax is not "shorthand for `classmethod(cmeth(cls, arg))`"; that would be applying `classmethod` to the _result_ of calling `cmeth`. The decorator instead applies `classmethod` to `cmeth` itself. That is, applying the `@classmethod` decorator to `cmeth` is syntatic sugar for doing `cmeth = classmethod(cmeth)` _after_ the `cmeth` definition.